# Need help in creating RabbitMQ consumer as windows service?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

This code works fine with console application but it doesnt work with Windows service application.
//code to receive message from queue

```
 public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        const string EXCHANGE_NAME = "EXCHANGE3";
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
       //Rabbit MQ connection
        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare("task_queue", true, false, false, null);

                channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
                var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume("task_queue", false, consumer);
                //Waiting in loop to get message 
                while (true)
                {
                    var ea =
                        (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                    Object message = Desserialize(ea.Body);


                   //Acknowledge one or more delivered message
                    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the account the service runs under have access to the queue?

Comment: My service is running under local system. How can I check whether queue can be accessed by Local system?

Comment: I don't know how to manage queue permissions on RabbitMQ, but if your service is running as local system and the queue is remote, you my need to [set up network access](http://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account) for it, which will only work if you are in a domain environment. Running the service as a specific service user and granting access to that user is the best way.